How to fix RenderFlex overflowed by pixels in Flutter?
M_cart_tile.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foodelivery/components/my_quantity_selector.dart';
import 'package:foodelivery/models/cart_item.dart';
import 'package:foodelivery/models/restaurant.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyCartTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final CartItem cartItem;

  const MyCartTile({super.key, required this.cartItem});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Restaurant>(
      builder: (context, restaurant, child) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  //food image
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      cartItem.food.imagePath,
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
              
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
              
                  //name and price
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      //food name
                      Text(cartItem.food.name),
              
                      //food price
                      Text(
                        '\$' + cartItem.food.price.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  const Spacer(),
              
                  //increment or decrement quantity
                  QuantitySelectorr(
                    quantity: cartItem.quantity, 
                    food: cartItem.food, 
                    onDecrement: () {
                      restaurant.removeFromCart(cartItem);
                    }, 
                    onIncrement: () {
                      restaurant.addToCart(
                        cartItem.food, cartItem.selectedAddons);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            //addons
            SizedBox(
              height: cartItem.selectedAddons.isEmpty ? 0 : 60,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10),
                children: cartItem.selectedAddons
                  .map(
                    (addon) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                      child: FilterChip(
                      label: Row(
                        children: [
                          //addon name
                          Text(addon.name),
                      
                          //addon price
                          Text(' (\$${addon.price})'),
                      
                        ],
                      ),
                      shape: StadiumBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onSelected: (value) {},
                      backgroundColor: 
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ).toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

quantity_selector.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foodelivery/models/food.dart';

class QuantitySelectorr extends StatelessWidget {
    final int quantity;
    final Food food;
    final VoidCallback onIncrement;
    final VoidCallback onDecrement;

  const QuantitySelectorr({
    super.key,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.food,
    required this.onDecrement,
    required this.onIncrement,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [

          //decrement button
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: onDecrement,
            child: Icon(
                Icons.remove,
                size: 20,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
          ),

          //quantity count
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 20,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  quantity.toString(),
                ),
              ),
            ), 
          ),

          //increment button
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: onIncrement,
            child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 20,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Above is the code which is giving this exception: A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.0 pixels on the right.
Now, i have tried wrapping the Row to flexible and QuerySelectorr to flexible but nothing seems to change.
The code seems to be working for the web, threre's not any RenderFlex error.
Only on phone its giving the exception.
I have also added file for quantity selector, as i think thats's where the fault may be.
screenshot

The problem is that you have Column with a texts that is taking larger texts than expected!
also if you have a product or item with a longer name than the "Classic burger" in the screenshot the overflow will be increased
usually in such cases, item's name would have a maximum 2 lines, and because the quantity selector widget is more important than the long item's name (I suppose you have an item details screen to know full details of the product)
it's better to wrap the item's name Column with an Expanded, so your M_cart_tile.dart code becomes:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foodelivery/components/my_quantity_selector.dart';
import 'package:foodelivery/models/cart_item.dart';
import 'package:foodelivery/models/restaurant.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyCartTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final CartItem cartItem;

  const MyCartTile({super.key, required this.cartItem});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Restaurant>(
      builder: (context, restaurant, child) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  //food image
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      cartItem.food.imagePath,
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
              
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
              
                  //name and price
///CHANGES IN THE NEXT LINE
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        //food name
                        Text(cartItem.food.name),
              
                        //food price
                        Text(
                          '\$' + cartItem.food.price.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  const Spacer(),
              
                  //increment or decrement quantity
                  QuantitySelectorr(
                    quantity: cartItem.quantity, 
                    food: cartItem.food, 
                    onDecrement: () {
                      restaurant.removeFromCart(cartItem);
                    }, 
                    onIncrement: () {
                      restaurant.addToCart(
                        cartItem.food, cartItem.selectedAddons);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            //addons
            SizedBox(
              height: cartItem.selectedAddons.isEmpty ? 0 : 60,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10),
                children: cartItem.selectedAddons
                  .map(
                    (addon) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                      child: FilterChip(
                      label: Row(
                        children: [
                          //addon name
                          Text(addon.name),
                      
                          //addon price
                          Text(' (\$${addon.price})'),
                      
                        ],
                      ),
                      shape: StadiumBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onSelected: (value) {},
                      backgroundColor: 
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ).toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}


Thanks! It worked, the exception is gone, but the text is overflowing to the next line classic c                                                        heeseburger. in this way, what can i do so every new text goes onto new line?

So you mean that the "cheeseburger" word got trimmed? this is a weird behavior! the whole word must go in a new line if the remaining space is insufficient
can you please update your question with the new screenshot and code?

No, it did not get trimmed, just went to a new line as you mentioned. Not the whole word though. Classic Ch were in first line and eeseburger in the next. I want that each word long enough to go into next line goes completely.

oh, got it, just remove the Spacer() or replace it with a SizedBox(width: 8)
